# What types of cadences work well in natural minor?

Tags: composition, cadence

I am currently interested in writing a piece in natural minor, and it seems like "v - i" cadence does not quite work as well as compared to harmonic and melodic minors, which use "V - i".  How can I write a good cadence in natural minor?  Would "VII - i" work well?

Comment: I use that sometimes, especially for C minor, I find that Bb -> Cm gives enough of a cadential feel. I personally feel the opposite about the v -> i vs V -> i in the first 5 flat minors. In those minor keys, the dominant seventh gives me too much of an expectation for a major key resolution for it to really sound good to me in minor. On the other hand I find the v -> i works just as well in minor as the dominant 7th does in major despite lacking the leading tone. It keeps the minor feel while giving enough of a sense that it wants to resolve for the Bb -> C motion to work.

Comment: Treating this modally would be different than treating it tonally. Modal pieces don't tend to have the same pull back to a tonic as tonal pieces, so cadences that establish a minor key _tonality_ are likely to be different from cadences that establish a minor _modality_. I am tempted to suggest [this question as a dupe](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42552/cadences-for-modes), but I am not quite sure that it answers your question.

Comment: Plagal works well  (IV-I).

Comment: @Jomiddnz But that's not part of natural minor.

Comment: ♭VI-♭VII-i is cool. i-♭VII-♭VII-v is also cool, like the Andalusian cadence but v instead of V. If you use that ♭VII chord and the v chord, it'll sound very strongly natural minor. i-iv-♭III-v shows how the iv degree is also very natural-minor-like.

Comment: user45266 // you mean i-VII-**VI**-v, not two VIIs...?

Comment: VI - i will sound fine. Lady in black sends its greetings.

Comment: @DavidBowling, no, actually.  I made an edit to make my intention clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bets will be v(7)-i, VII-i, and iv-i. For a piece that uses all of these, including both perfect and imperfect cadences, listen to (I'm remembering back to old choir days): "[I Know That My Redeemer Liveth](https://www.sheetmusicplus.com/title/i-know-that-my-redeemer-liveth-sheet-music/35012)" by Joseph M. Martin.