# Why can't cadences like V-I or IV-I be viewed modally?

Tags: harmony

My previous revision of http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42552/cadences-for-modes/81464#81464 looked like this:

> - Ionian: **V - I**
> - Dorian: **IV - i** or **V(no3) - i**
> - Phrygian: II - i or ***V(no5 no3)* - i**
> - Lydian: II - I or **V - I**
> - Mixolydian: VII - I or **V(no3) - I**
> - Aeolian: **V(no3) - i**
> - Locrian: VI - i(no5) or **V - i(no5)**

And Dom had given me some replies:

> *"Again, if you want to utilize modes, tonal is typically not the goal so tonal concepts may not matter at all. The edit doesn't change any of the concerns I have about your post, it's just doubling down on issues I've raised."*
>
> *"See previous comments."*
>
> *"I honestly don't know what you are tying to say in your answer anymore. I told you why I down voted and you keep tweeking your answer, but you are missing the point. You aren't talking about the modes, your just listing what you think a cadence is and not describing how to approach cadences in modes. Even concepts like omitting notes is taking your concepts too far."*
>
> *"@MaikaSakuranomiya again you are not listening to my feedback which is this entire chat. Any **V-I** or **IV-I** will not be viewed modally. Concepts like **V(no5)(no3)** are not real and are the mangling of trying to cram tonal theory into modal. You just pull cadences out of nowhere and don't try to talk about any concepts."*
>
> *"Maika, you are not listening to feedback. I feel like further discussions on this are not going to be fruitful."*

---

So, the question is: how come V-I or IV-I cadences can only be viewed tonally, and not modally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up any classical theory book that covers cadences. They will go over V-I, I-V, IV-I, V-i, etc. all in tonal contexts. You were building your theories with this in mind, but you need to remember classical theories all stem from the idea of tonal harmony. You are using the primary chords and the leading tone to get back to the tonic.

When focusing on the flavor of the modes, doing tonal ideas takes away from the modal flavor. This isn't bad when just writing, but when you want to use the natural flavors of the modes it dilutes the concepts of you using them.  For example, just doing  V-I in Lydian and not focusing on the ♯4 in the melody or the harmony, you really aren't enforcing the idea of Lydian.

Answer (score 4):

If modal stuff worked tonally, and tonal stuff worked modally, we wouldn't be using two different, separate terms. The only modes that work in what we percieve a tonal way are the Ionian and to a degree, the Aeolian. The latter, because we feel the need to have a leading note, and that's only afforded when we change Aeolian into harmonic or melodic minors - both tonal in their own right, and having modes of their own.

Having the same notes in each doesn't make them interchangeable, and the concept of any modal work relies on the fact that its notes do *not* work in the same manner as tonal stuff. If that was the case, the two would be pretty well synonymous - which they're not.

A possible analogy - the alphabet contains letters. They can be used in many different laguages (mainly with no changes), so we could ask the question - why doesn't French/German/Italian work the same way as English? But we don't.